# How can I fix Xcode's Build & Analyze?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode5, clang-static-analyzer

After installing Xcode 6, my Xcode 5 seems to have stopped performing static analysis on my main app target. I can run Build & Analyze and it turns up static analysis issues in sub projects, but not my main target.

I've tried reinstalling Xcode 5, but it has not helped. I have also tried installing the clang-checker separately and following the [instructions for incorporating it into Xcode](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html). After installing the clang-checker I'm seeing analysis for *some* of the files in my app target, but not all of them. It looks like any C++ or Objective-C++ files in my project are not being analyzed.

If I run `scan-build` from the command line to try to analyze my project outside of Xcode, I get "analyzer issues" with all of the .mm files.

Has anybody got any suggestions for fixes for this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `xcode-select -p`?

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer. That's my Xcode 5.1.1 install. I have Xcode 6.0.1 installed as /Applications/Xcode6.app.